# How to remove cookies for requests by given conditions from haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I'm using haproxy with varnish caching.

I want to create a configuration which accomplish the following:
When requests arrive from given URL starting with '/xyz' and when header contains cookie size > v then remove the cookie from header, and send it to a backend (in my case varnish).

How can I create such condition in haproxy.cfg? 
Is it possible to check cookie size with haproxy.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this configuration using a backend that checks if URL begins with certain string. Then inside the backend I used the `http-request del-header` directive to remove the cookie from header.